# Solving a large system of coupled ode. (Python)

Tags: python, ode

I really have a problem here. I have not found a solution yet. The system I need to solve similar to this:(Basic idea)

$$c_1 = \dfrac{dx}{dr}+y$$

$$c_2 = \dfrac{dy}{dr}+x$$

Both $c_1/ c_2$ are equal to `0` meaning the desired system is:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dr} = -x$$ and $$\dfrac{dx}{dr} = -y$$

The ODE system I wanna solve is the above with  Initial Values given $(x0,y0,r0)$ and needs to be solved for the space $(r0,rf)$

Generally, the $c$ expressions  are quantities of: `x,y,dx,dy,r` and more specific

**IMPORTANT** I'm in no position to solve with respect to dx,dy. Although this example is easy, (2 variables), I got 12 Variables and the `Expr` are super large.

**Generally**, I would like to solve  this system:

$$A\cdot \dfrac{dX}{dr} + B\cdot X= 0 $$

where `X` is a set of Variables,  and `A,B` are Square Matrix of the Length of X.

Is there any routine I can Solve it in that form?

Comment: I don't understand how both `Expr` are equal to zero, but also contain quantities `x,y,dx,dy,r`.

Comment: I also don't understand what `dx,dy` are. Are these $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$?

Comment: And finally, since there does not appear to be a term $dr/dt$, how come you need/are given initial conditions `r0` for this function?

Comment: Is it possible to writing down the expressions by using LaTeX that we have here to make your question clearer? I agree Wolfgang cause it's not clear at all what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I did use Latex now. Sorry for not using before :( 1st time in this SE. Thought I could not write.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think you are right, I miss-wrote the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Is $A$ invertible? if yes, the solution is somehow obvious and I can post an answer for you.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Yeah. I will verify it tommorow, but please I would love the answer if you can post it :)

Comment: What's the difficulty you are experiencing? That's a completely standard problem that the documentation of every ODE solver should explain how to solve.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm not that experienced in programming, although I have solved before an ODE system. I don't know any form that works with this.

Comment: @billy: There is absolutely nothing special about your ODE. It isn't even large. People solve ODEs with thousands of variables every day, and it's not a big deal. But the real point I wanted to make is that (i) there are outstanding resources out there for you to learn how to do this, (ii) your post doesn't actually contain a question. It's just not clear to any of us what specifically you need help with.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I did not say its special. I just asked if there was a routine I could solve it maintaining that form. I said I'm not experienced. I did not say I was Expert. I have solved ODEs before but in the form of $X' = A X$ not $AX' +BX =0$. That's all I asked...

Comment: But what you have is a common problem as well. Every PDE discretization yields a system of the form $MX'+AX=F$. There should be plenty of documentation on these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve this matrix ODE system as:

$$A \mathbf{x}^{'}(r) = -B \mathbf{x}(r)$$

where: $\mathbf{x}^{'}(r) = \frac{d \mathbf{x}}{dr}$. If $A$ is invertible:

$$\mathbf{x}^{'}(r) = -A^{-1} B \mathbf{x}(r)$$

The general solution is:

$$\mathbf{x}(r) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i} \exp{(\lambda_{i} r)} \mathbf{u}_{i}$$

Where $\lambda_{i}$ and $\mathbf{u}_{i}$ are eigenvalue and eigenvector of $-A^{-1} B$ matrix. These eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be extracted easily by something like SVD. $c_{i}$ are constants that depend on your initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)$. I'm not sure why you got stuck because as Wolfgang said it is just very routine method to solve system of ODEs.

**Update**: A less expensive approach to avoid inverting $A$ directly, may be using a backward Euler method to solve this system of ODEs numerically:

$$A \frac{\mathbf{x}(r+\Delta r) - \mathbf{x}(r)}{\Delta r} = -B \mathbf{x} (r+\Delta r)$$

or:

$$(A + \Delta r B) \mathbf{x} (r+\Delta r) = A \mathbf{x} (r)$$

Please be aware that to work with all of these methods including the direct method to invert $A$ and this numerical scheme, you **must** have $A$ and $B$ available. The above equation is just a linear equation when you know $\mathbf{x}(r)$ from previous step and you can solve for $\mathbf{x}(r+\Delta r)$ by using **any** linear equation solver available in Python, C, C++, etc.

Comment: Sorry I asked this. Although with this method seperate ALL elements from the system. 

I only have the final Matrix $$C(X,X')=0$$ (1-Row)  which can be written $$C(X,X') = AX'+BX =0$$ but I need to write functions to seperate each component, right? There is no easy way?

Comment: What do you mean I have the final matrix? $C$ is just a vector. Also, if you have just $C$, it means you have a vector with all components equal to zero... so what? I agree @WolfgangBangerth, your question is so vague...